# Starting eclipse from unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, eclipse

I downloaded the eclipse from its site. And extracted in home folder. For the first time when I opened it, it worked fine. Then I locked it to launcher. Now it's not starting when I click on launcher icon in eclipse but it starts when I start it from the folder where I extracted it. Please tell some way to keep it in launchcer and open it from t here only.

Thanks.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Java - SnapdealOMS/src/main/java/com/snapdeal/oms/admin/web/controller/ReloadCacheController.java - Eclipse 
Icon=eclipse.png
Path=/home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse
Exec=/usr/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -data /home/nakulkumar/Snapdeal_workspace -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash /home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp -launcher /home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so -startup /home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 34000f -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Comment: You must have an old(er) .desktop file, probably in `~/.local/share/applications`, linking to the wrong directory/executable.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: Could you tell me how you installed it? Did you install another version before (and how was that one installed/uninstalled)

Comment: No other version was installed just using another workspace. Now it neither switching to another workspace nor starting. Just extarcted to home hoolder and started using it.

Comment: AHA, could you run `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` and post what is in the line staring with`Exec=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, When you run `Eclipse` from a downloaded version, it should create a *correct* `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` on first run.

In this case, for some reason, some lines were messed up:

- The `Exec=` -line should simply show the path to your executable.
- The `Name=` -line obviously went (terribly) wrong as well

#### How to fix

Just replace:

- The line starting with `Exec=` by:

  ```
  Exec=/path/to/your/eclipse_executable
  ```

  (most likely, looking at your `Path=` -line, it should be: `Exec=/home/nakulkumar/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse`)
- The line starting with `Name=` by:

  ```
  Name=Java - Eclipse
  ```

As a comparison, this is the `.desktop` file Eclipse created on my system:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Java - Eclipse 
Icon=eclipse
Path=/home/jacob/eclipse
Exec=/home/jacob/eclipse/eclipse
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Comment: @coder005 Glad it worked out!

Comment: It doesn't look like eclipse created a .desktop file for me, what is the name of the file, or can I just make my own and name it whatever I want?